# Hive insert query failing with error return code -101

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, apache-tez

I am trying to run a simple insert statement as below:

```
insert into table `bwc_test` partition(call_date)
select * from
`bwc_master`;
```

Then it fails with the below error:

INFO  : Loading data to table dtc.bwc_test partition (call_date=null) from /apps/hive/warehouse/dtc.db/bwc_test/.hive-staging_hive_2018-11-13_19-10-37_084_8697431764330812894-1/-ext-10000

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. HIVE_LOAD_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS_THREAD_COUNT (state=08S01,code=-101)
```

Table definition for bwc_master:

```
CREATE TABLE `bwc_master`(                                   
unique_id bigint,                                           
customer_id string,                                         
direction string,                                           
call_date_time timestamp,                                   
duration int,                                               
billed_duration int,                                        
retail_rate decimal(9,7),                                   
retail_cost decimal(19,7),                                  
billed_tier smallint,                                       
call_type tinyint,                                          
record_status tinyint,                                      
aggregate_id bigint,                                        
originating_ipaddress string,                               
originating_number string,                                  
destination_number string,                                  
lrn string,                                                 
ocn string,                                                 
destination_rate_center string,                             
destination_lata int,                                       
billed_prefix string,                                       
rate_id string,                                             
wholesale_rate decimal(9,7),                                
wholesale_cost decimal(19,7),                               
cnam_dipped boolean,                                        
billed_number_type tinyint,                                 
source_lata int,                                            
source_ocn string,                                          
location_id string,                                         
sippeer_id int,                                             
rate_attempts tinyint,                                      
source_state string,                                        
source_rc string,                                           
destination_country string,                                 
destination_state string,                                   
destination_ip string,                                      
carrier_id string,                                          
rated_date_time timestamp,                                  
partition_id smallint,                                      
encryption_rate decimal(9,7),                               
encryption_cost decimal(19,7),                              
trans_coding_rate decimal(9,7),                             
trans_coding_cost decimal(19,7),                            
file_name string,                                           
call_id string,                                             
from_tag string,                                            
to_tag string,                                              
unique_record_id string)                                    

PARTITIONED BY (                                                
`call_date` date)  

CLUSTERED BY (                                                  
customer_id)                                                  
INTO 10 BUCKETS 

ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'  

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                           
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'

OUTPUTFORMAT                                                    
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'    

LOCATION                                                        
'hdfs://*****/apps/hive/warehouse/dtc.db/bwc_master'
```

Can someone help me debug this? I didn't find anything in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You missing the "table" before `bwc_test`

```
insert into  table `bwc_test` partition(call_date)
select * from
`bwc_master`;
```

Comment: Could you please update your table definition as well?

Comment: The query that you used to create the table

Comment: @AndyReddy did you define your partition column id?

Comment: @AndyReddy One more thing did you create the `bwc_test` table first ?Moreover,  Could you please describe what results are you looking for?

Comment: bwc_master is the original table created first....i am just trying to insert the records into the test table which has the same table definition....So its a simple insert job...